# passing props to childrens using React.cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You can do this

```
<div>
<MyComponent ...this.props/>
</div>
```

to pass props to MyComponent, but if you want to make MyComponent as a children you have to use

```
<div>{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}</div>
```

Is there any alternative to cloneElement? I'm using babel I try not to write in older way.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ? you want to render the `MyComponent` inside `div` and want to pass the `props` ?

Comment: If what you're trying to do is pass props to already rendered children, then yes, you must clone it and pass in new props.

Comment: @ndugger what is the new syntax for React.cloneElement?

Comment: Why do you think there's a "new syntax" to replace it?

Comment: @MayankShukla pass the props and render it as children?

Comment: ndugger because React.createClass is not needed, I assume React.something is also obsoleted?

Comment: That assumption is wrong; `React.cloneElement` is still standard.

Comment: What do mean by making MyComponent as a children?

Answer (score 0):

The props object is read only, which means something like `this.props.children[0].props = {...}` will not work. You must use `React.cloneElement`.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

> React is pretty flexible but it has a single strict rule:
>
> **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.**

If you have a component reading and manipulating the props of it's child, the child may not be pure anymore. So you need to clone a new one.